# Add new element to array with setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to add new element to array with setState

I have this data

```
this.state = {
    items : [
   { "id" : "324", "parent" : "qqqq", "text" : "Simple root node" },
   { "id" : "24", "parent" : "dwdw", "text" : "Root node" },
   { "id" : "55", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Ch" },
   { "id" : "9866", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "oiiojio" },
]
    }
```

I'm mapping the data

```
{this.state.items.sort((a,b) => a.newID < b.newID).map((item)=>
   <ul>
     <li key={item.id}><span>ID: </span>{item.id} <span>parent: </span>{item.parent} <span>text: </span>{item.text}</li>
   </ul>
   )}
```

and then I'm sorting the data by `newID` That I need to create it with setState

```
this.setState(prevState=>({newData: [...prevState.items, this.props.account.info]}));
```

How can I create new element with `this.props.account.info` add somthing like `i++` I don't know actually

`this.props.account.info` It's adding data like

```
{ "id" : "324", "parent" : "qqqq", "text" : "Simple root node" }
```

So I need to add an element inside this will be like

```
{ "newID": "1", "id" : "324", "parent" : "qqqq", "text" : "Simple root node" }
```

Comment: "but this only sorting by ID, Do I add an element only for sorting" depends on your requirements, which we don't know. What should you sort for?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I edited my question cus it wasn't clear enough

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to add "newID" field in the object, there is a way to do this using object spread operator.

```
{...this.props.account.info, "newID":"1"}
```

This will give you a new object with the "newID" field added with "1" as its value associated with it.

This is a shorthand for this:

```
Object.assign({}, this.props.account.info, {"newID": "1"});
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, I need to add new ID element will gives deffrenet value for each item.